# Fixed Calculated Column in Reporting Service Header

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, reporting-services, webforms, ssrs-2008

I'm using Reporting Service in .net core

I want to display the total cost in the Report header, it calculated by the sum function
and it only get the right result be display in the table that view data

How to calculate this column and display the Result in Fixed header ??

[image]

Comment: Fixed Header is part of the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
=Sum(Fields!TotalCost.Value, "YourDataSetName")
```

This expression can also be used in a single textbox, which you put into your report.

And btw your TotalCost column has to be from type numeric. If this is the error source use a

```
CDbl(Fields!TotalCost.Value)
```

before the function.